# Is there any browser to view the content of Berkeley DB file?

Tags: berkeley-db

For SQLite db we can use SQLite Browser to do CRUD operations and view the .db file. Are there any interface to view the content of a Berkeley DB file?

Answer (score 2):

Berkeley DB includes a sqlite library wrapper (it's exactly an sqlite API) that should work with your sqlite browser.

Note that not all Berkeley DB databases can be used under the sqlite layer: there are some constraints on the data storage if the sqlite wrapper is used.

Using db_dump will display the key -> value pairs in a Berkeley DB in hex.